# Unity2D: unity crashes when trying to slice a sprite sheet

Tags: image, unity-game-engine

I successfully imported the following [sprite sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mje1o.jpg) into my project and change the 'Sprite Mode' to multiple so that I can slice it, however, when I try slicing it, unity crashes. I opened up a new unity project to see if I using too much VRAM but when I attempt slicing the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mje1o.jpg) as well unity crashes. It may be because of my laptop not being able to handle it due to its own RAM being low or it could be because of the sprite sheet being too large, i'm not quite sure. Will someone be able to give me some insight into my problem, please and thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Split your spritesheet into 2 or 4 smaller spritesheets and try reimporting and slicing those.**

All right, first of all, when you uploaded the spritesheet to imgur, imgur compressed it to jpg, resized it and removed all transparency, so we can't recreate the issue you're having.

However, I did a reverse image search, found the full-sized png and discovered that the height of the spritesheet is 8609px. A good max height and width for importing textures/images would be 2048 and is the default option to which your spritesheet will be resized to after import. You can override this option in the inspector [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZKo2.png) to 4096 or 8192 for different platforms, but the height of your spritesheet still exceeds these values and might be messing with the internals of unity, not sure how.

So, for starters, split your spritesheet into 2 or 4 smaller spritesheets and try reimporting and slicing those. This is what I'd recommend doing anyway, e.g. create a separate spritesheet *for jump, punch, kick, die, walk*, it'll probably be easier to manage and edit if needed.